# fabricjs on retina: new object jumps to left top

Tags: fabricjs, retina

I continue my work on collaborative sketch tool and trying to add retina devices support. Currently i have following behavior if user creating drawing on ipad air:
[small movie](https://youtu.be/-yCqFe-SGGw)

Here is my code:

```
this.getZoomLevel = function (height) {
            if (height > 1024) {
                return 1024 / height;
            } else {
                return height / 1024;
            }
        };  

this.calculateCanvasSize = function(pHeight, pWidth) {
            var result = {
                height: 0,
                width: 0
            };

            while (result.width < pWidth - 1 && result.height < pHeight - 1) {
                result.height = result.height + 1;
                result.width = result.height * 4 / 3;
            }
            return result;
        }; 

this.initCanvas = function () {
            try {
                var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('komaso-canvas-container')[0];
                var canvasSize = this.calculateCanvasSize(parent.clientHeight, parent.clientWidth);

                var canvasHtml = "<div id='wrapper-" + this.Id + "' class='whiteboard-canvas-wrapper' data-ng-show='CurrentPage.Id==" + this.Id + "'><canvas width='" + canvasSize.width + "' height='" + canvasSize.height + "' id='whiteboard-" + this.Id + "' class='whiteboard'><p>Your brower does not support Canvas/p></canvas></div>";
                $(parent).append($compile(canvasHtml)(scope));

                this.Canvaso = document.getElementById(this.HtmlId);

                if (!this.Canvaso) {
                    console.log('Error: Cannot find the imageView canvas element!');
                    return;
                }

                if (!this.Canvaso.getContext) {
                    console.log('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
                    return;
                }

                this.FabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.HtmlId, { selectionColor: 'transparent' });

                this.FabricCanvas.setWidth(canvasSize.width);
                this.FabricCanvas.setHeight(canvasSize.height);

                fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

                this.FabricCanvas.on('mouse:down', this.onMouseDown);
                this.FabricCanvas.on('mouse:up', this.onMouseUp);
                this.FabricCanvas.on('mouse:move', this.onMouseMove);
                this.FabricCanvas.on('object:added', this.onObjectAdded);
                this.FabricCanvas.on('text:editing:exited', self.onTextObjectEdited);

                if (window.devicePixelRatio !== 1) {

                    var c = this.FabricCanvas.getElement(); 
                    var w = c.width, h = c.height;

                    c.setAttribute('width', w * window.devicePixelRatio);
                    c.setAttribute('height', h * window.devicePixelRatio);

                    $(c).width(canvasSize.width);
                    $(c).height(canvasSize.height);

                    c.getContext('2d').scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
                }

                this.FabricCanvas.setZoom(this.getZoomLevel(this.Canvaso.height));

                this.ToggleTool(self.CurrentTool.ToolName);
                this.WhiteboardInitiated = true;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        };
```

getZoomLevel returns value to pass into SetZoom method of fabric js canvas object. We decided to have all clients canvas aspects are 4:3 and default dimension is 1024*768. So based on this dimensions we calculation zoom factor.

calculateCanvasSize - returns width and height for canvas according to 4:3 rule.

If you have any idea about how to fix this wrong behavior then post your comment please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what version of fabric are you using?

Comment: Hi Andrea. We are using 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you yo update to a retina enabled version of fabricjs (grab 1.6.2).

If, for any reason you can't, i think the problem is here:

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio !== 1) {
   var c = this.FabricCanvas.getElement(); 
   ...
   c.getContext('2d').scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
}
```

getContext return a new context. This is not the context where fabric is gonna render later. If you want to have retina enabled lowerCanvas you have to scale `this.FabricCanvas.contextContainer` that gets created and referenced on fabric.Canvas initialization.

I suggest you to switch to newer fabric anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Will try to use your recommendations